# Why overriding mousePressEvent in PyQt makes clicking signal doesn't trigger?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am writing a software with Python 3.5 and PyQt5. When I override mousePressEvent of QTableWidget the cellClicked signal doesn't trigger anymore. I need overriding mousePressEvent for getting the pos of mouse clicking and cellClicked for doing another job for cells that are clicked. Why it is like this? Where is the problem? 
This is my code for overriding the events:

```
class QTableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def checking(self):
        if (self.endgingposx - self.startingposx) >= 50:
            self.clear()
    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        event.accept()
        self.startingposx = event.x()
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        event.accept()
        self.endgingposx = event.x()
        self.checking()
```

and this is my clicking signal and it's connected slot:

```
self.main_table.cellClicked.connect(self.populatescnte)

def populatescnte(self,row,column):
    itemnum = self.scentence_listw.count()
    exec("item{} = QListWidgetItem(QIcon('content/img/food.png'),'{}')".format(itemnum+1,self.main_table.cellWidget(row,column).text))
    exec("self.scentence_listw.addItem(item{})".format(itemnum+1))
```

self.scentence_listw is a QListWidget. 
Thank you in advance.

---

**Update**
Thank you every body this code works for me:

```
class myTableWidget(QTableWidget):
def checking(self):
    if (self.endgingposx - self.startingposx) >= 50:
    self.clear()
def mousePressEvent(self,event):
    super().mousePressEvent(event)
    self.startingposx = event.x()
def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
    super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
    self.endgingposx = event.x()
    self.checking()
```

Comment: (Don't know much Python or QT warning) - When you override an event handler for GUIs, that traditionally means the original event handler isn't called any more. The click is probably generated by that original handler. To get that back, your replacement handler should directly call the original handler - probably calling the same event handler name but for the base class. BTW - am I reading the top line right? Do you have the same name for the base and derived class? That might make it hard to call base-class methods (eg that original handler), though I don't remember enough Python to be sure.

Comment: @Steve314 if I change the name of derived class the changed event doesn't happen. How can i call the original handler directly?

Comment: You need to call super for `mousePressEvent` for the original handler to kick in.

Comment: @DanielePantaleone I wrote this: `super().mousePressEvent()` but it gives error for sending not enoghu arguemnts that is a QMouseEvent i put that but it gives error for it's arguments. what is the correct way?

Comment: You need to pass the QMouseEvent instance to the original handler: super().mousePressEvent(event)

Comment: @Nimda - sorry - to answer your question, I'd first have to learn QT and re-learn Python. However, giving the base and derived class the same name isn't right. I can only suggest Googling for some PyQT event handling tutorials.

Comment: @daniele-pantaleone it doesn't make difference . Still the clicking signal doesn't trigger.

Comment: Please update your code whenever you do some modifications ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event isn't being propagated because you have accepted it in your handler.

You allow need to call the the original handler.

FWIW, you can hook up a handler to `itemSelectionChanged` and get the `selectedItems` on the table rather than tracking positions.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, 
    QTableWidgetItem, QGridLayout
)


class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()    

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple')

        table = TrackedTableWidget()

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.show()


class TrackedTableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()    

    def initUI(self):
        self.setRowCount(2)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem('30', 0));
        self.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem('40', 0));
        self.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem('50', 0));
        self.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem('60', 0));

        self.cellClicked.connect(self._handle_cell_clicked)
        self.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self._handle_item_selection)

    def _handle_cell_clicked(self, row, column):
        print('cell_clicked', row, column)
        print('selected cell positions', self.startingposx, self.endingposx)

    def _handle_item_selection(self, *args):
        print(self.selectedItems())
        print('item_selection', args)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print('mousePressEvent')
        self.startingposx = event.x()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print('mouseReleaseEvent')
        self.endingposx = event.x()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### Reference

- [About accepting events](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qevent.html#accept)

Comment: Is this after you made the change stated by @Steve314?

Comment: i made that changes and said what happened.

Comment: Nothing changes. With or without having super method i test having accept line but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I handle the event as follow:

```
class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Ui, self).__init__() # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
    uic.loadUi('./mainwindow.ui', self) # Load the .ui file

    self.myButton.pressed.connect(self.mousePress)

    self.show() # Show the GUI

  def mousePress(self):
     print("Mouse pressed")
```