# QGraphicsView.DragMode with middle mouse button

Tags: python, pyside6, pyqt6

I encountered the problem indicated in the title. The only solutions I found were quite old and perhaps something has changed since then and now it is possible to make the DragMode.ScrollHandDrag action for the middle mouse key?

```
class InfiniteCanvas(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(InfiniteCanvas, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.DragMode.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.left_mouse_active = False

        screen = QApplication.primaryScreen()
        screen_size = screen.size()
        width = screen_size.width() * 0.7
        height = screen_size.height() * 0.7

        self.setGeometry(self.x(), self.y(), width, height)

        self.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: #2a2a2a;")

   def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
        self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)  
        self.original_event = event
        handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonPress,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
        self.mousePressEvent(handmade_event)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.acceptProposedAction()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = InfiniteCanvas()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This is the sample code I use in the mousePressEvent method however it completely rules out the possibility of using the left mouse button for anything else.

Comment: Except for small or even irrelevant changes, doing this is fundamentally identical to what could have been done since Qt4, since more than 10 years ago. So, either you found all the wrong solutions, or you didn't apply them properly. In any case, please provide a valid [mre] of your attempts, otherwise this question will easily be closed as a duplicate of many similar ones.

Comment: Please, provide a *valid and complete* [mre]. For instance, you should also similarly override `mouseMoveEvent()`, but we cannot know if you actually did it or not, or if you did something wrong in there.

Comment: you put code with wrong indentations - so it is hard to say if all problem is because you have wrong indentation in some places.

Comment: frankly, you could add all needed `import` in example code - so we could simply copy code to run it and test problem.

Comment: maybe you have to use `return True` at the end of `mousePressEvent`. OR maybe you have to use `super()` to execute original version of `mousePressEvent`. `super().mousePressEvent(event)`

Comment: it seems solution can be `super().mousePressEvent(event)`  at the end of own `mousePressEvent()`. See: [python - Why overriding mousePressEvent in PyQt makes clicking signal doesn't trigger? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933021/why-overriding-mousepressevent-in-pyqt-makes-clicking-signal-doesnt-trigger)

Comment: @furas That's only part of the problem, as there needs to be a `mouseReleaseEvent()` override to handle the middle button release too. Note that specific event handlers like `mousePressEvent()` are `void`, so any return value in Python is ignored (other than technically wrong), the only difference may be eventually made by accepting or ignoring the event.

Comment: @musicamante I'm not sure but it seems `QGraphicsView` has some code in original `mouseReleaseEvent()` to work with `left mouse`- so if you override it then it can't run original code and `left mouse` doesn't work. And it needs `super().mousePressEvent(event)` to run original code for `left mouse`. But all this would need full working code with some example elements on `QGraphicsView` to use `left mouse`.

Comment: @furas Sorry, I'm probably too tired to understand your comment :-/ What I meant is that a proper implementation should *also* override `mouseReleaseEvent()` and synthesize a left-button release. This is because: 1. QGraphicsView sets an internal flag for its "scrolling state" when the left button is pressed, so that state has to be restored when the middle button (aka, the fake left button release event); 2. if the cursor is overridden in the mouse press, it has to be restored in the mouse release. The OP made some confusion, as setting the cursor wasn't necessary for their approach.

Comment: @musicamante I saw your code in answer and it seems we have similar ideas - main element is to use `super()` to run original `mousePressEvent()` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call the default `mousePressEvent` with the synthesized left click event, but since you overrode that function without ever calling the base implementation, nothing will happen.

When you do the following:

```py
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)  
            self.original_event = event
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(...)
            self.mousePressEvent(handmade_event)
```

then the *same* `mousePressEvent()` will be called again from itself, but since now the button is the left one, the block within `if event.button() == Qt.MidButton` is skipped and there's nothing else to do after that: the event is completely ignored, because you are *overriding* its expected behavior.

Your attempt to fix that with `dragEnterEvent()` and `dragMoveEvent()` is pointless and wrong, because those handlers are related to actual [*drag and drop*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/dnd.html), which is a different type of event management, used to drag *objects* that may eventually be *dropped* onto other components, even between different applications.

The correct procedure would be to add an `else` clause and call `super()` with the default event handler:

```py
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.MiddleButton:
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(
                QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress, 
                event.position(), Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton, 
                event.buttons(), event.modifiers())
            super().mousePressEvent(handmade_event)
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)
```

Note the changes done above:

1. There is no need to change the cursor, since the call to `mousePressEvent()` with the left button will do that on its own when the `ScrollHandDrag` mode is set;
2. Since Qt6, `event.pos()` has been deprecated, and you should use `event.position()` instead (which already is a QPointF);
3. Since Qt6 both PySide and PyQt use real Python enums, which need their specific namespaces; PySide6 has a "forgiveness mode" that still allows the old syntax, but its usage is now discouraged (as annoying as it can be);
4. `MidButton` has been virtually considered obsolete for years, and it's deprecated since 5.15; the correct name is `MiddleButton`;

Then, QGraphicsView *assumes* the scrolling state set from the left button event, and it ignores the actual `buttons()` in `mouseMoveEvent()`, allowing scrolling movements even if the left button is not actually pressed while moving. In reality, though, we should still theoretically override that too, similarly to what done before. Be aware of that, in case it will stop working for you in a future Qt version.

Finally, we *must* do the same in the `mouseReleaseEvent()` in order to tell the internal state of graphics view that the mouse button has been released (even if virtually), which will also restore the cursor.

```py
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.MiddleButton:
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(
                QEvent.Type.MouseButtonRelease, 
                event.position(), Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton, 
                event.buttons(), event.modifiers())
            super().mouseReleaseEvent(handmade_event)
        else:
            super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

Be aware that all the above will **never** work as soon as the scene rect shown on the the view can fit its geometry, because the `ScrollHandDrag` only works within the scroll bar range (the fact that you made them invisible is irrelevant).

If you actually want to be able to scroll no matter the scene rect size (which is what you probably need, given the name of your class), you cannot do it with the above.

Instead, you should set a scene rect on the view that is large enough to allow (virtually) infinite scrolling, ensure that you properly set the [`transformationAnchor`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsview.html#transformationAnchor-prop) to `NoAnchor`, and then call [`translate()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsview.html#translate) in `mouseMoveEvent()` with the delta of the current mouse movement.

```py
from random import randrange
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

class InfiniteCanvas(QGraphicsView):
    _isScrolling = _isSpacePressed = False
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(InfiniteCanvas, self).__init__(parent)

        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        for _ in range(10):
            item = scene.addRect(randrange(1000), randrange(1000), 50, 50)
            item.setFlag(item.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setScene(scene)

        self.setRenderHints(
            QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing
            | QPainter.RenderHint.SmoothPixmapTransform
        )
        # Important! Without this, self.translate() will not work!
        self.setTransformationAnchor(self.ViewportAnchor.NoAnchor)

        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        screen = QApplication.screenAt(QCursor.pos())
        geo = screen.availableGeometry()
        geo.setSize(geo.size() * .7)
        geo.moveCenter(screen.availableGeometry().center())
        self.setGeometry(geo)

        self.setSceneRect(-32000, -32000, 64000, 64000)

        self.fitInView(scene.itemsBoundingRect())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if (
            event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.MiddleButton
            or self._isSpacePressed
            and event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton
        ):
            self._isScrolling = True
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.CursorShape.ClosedHandCursor)
            self.scrollPos = event.position()
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._isScrolling:
            newPos = event.position()
            delta = newPos - self.scrollPos
            t = self.transform()
            self.translate(delta.x() / t.m11(), delta.y() / t.m22())
            self.scrollPos = newPos
        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self._isScrolling:
            self._isScrolling = False
            if self._isSpacePressed:
                self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.CursorShape.OpenHandCursor)
            else:
                self.viewport().unsetCursor()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Space and not event.isAutoRepeat():
            self._isSpacePressed = True
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.CursorShape.OpenHandCursor)
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Space and not event.isAutoRepeat():
            self._isSpacePressed = False
            if not self._isScrolling:
                self.viewport().unsetCursor()
        else:
            super().keyReleaseEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = InfiniteCanvas()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

As an unrelated note, you shall never, *ever* set generic QSS properties on complex widgets like scroll areas (which is the case of QGraphicsView) or combo boxes, as you did with this line:

```
self.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: #2a2a2a;")
```

Doing so will propagate that property to *any* child widget (including scroll bars or context menus), which is very problematic for complex widgets like scroll areas or comboboxes.

You should *always* use proper [selector types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) instead, unless you are *completely sure* that you're applying the QSS to a simple standalone widget (like a button or a label).

Also see these related posts:

- [How to pan beyond the scrollbar range in a QGraphicsview?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19207153)
- [Allow QGraphicsView to move outside scene](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55007339)